# Similar to with regex in Postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

In Postgresql database I have a column called names where I have some names which need to be parsed using regex to clean up punctuation parts. I am able to get a clean name using regexp_replace as follows:

```
select regexp_replace(name,'\.COM|''[A-Z]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)(?:\s+|-)(?!\w\w)','','g') 
from tableA
```

However, I would like to compare with some strings that are also cleaned of punctuation. How can I use similar to with the formed regular expression?

```
select name
from tableA 
where (lower(name) ~ '\.COM|''[A-Za-z]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)(?:\s+|-)(?!\w\w)') as nameParsed similar to '(fg )%' and 
      (lower(name) ~ '\.COM|''[A-Za-z]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)(?:\s+|-)(?!\w\w)') as nameParsed similar to '%( cargo| carrier| cartage )%'
```

With the previous query I am getting this error:

```
LINE 3: ...-zA-Z0-9 -]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)(?:\s+|-)(?!\w\w)') as namePar...
```

I have tried in where clause like this and it seems to be working:

```
select name
from tableA 
where (select lower(regexp_replace(name,'\.COM|''[A-Z]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)(?:\s+|-)(?!\w\w)','','g'))) similar to '(fg )%'
```

Is this the best approach? The execution time went to 46 seconds :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get a column name in a WHERE clause (is a comparison, not a column). So, you can use as follows:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM "tableA"
 WHERE (regexp_replace(name,'\.COM|''[A-Z]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)(?:\s+|-)(?!\w\w)','','g') similar to '(fg )%' 
    OR regexp_replace(name,'\.COM|''[A-Z]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)(?:\s+|-)(?!\w\w)','','g') similar to '%( cargo| carrier| cartage )%');
```

Alternatively, you can use `ilike` instead of `similar to` if you want to find a specific word.